# Find elements defined in the LWUIT resource editor

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor

I'm developing a LWUIT based application and I have separated my application into one form which has to access components such as the given example log-in dialog.

Problem is I can't seem to find a way to access (or initialize) a container or dialog defined outside the currently displayed form because code like:

`findLoginDialog(Display.getInstance().getCurrent()).show();`

does not work. I also tried looking at inherited methods but saw that `showContainer(...)` also requires a source component.

Is it possible at all to do this or any work around?

Comment: Whilst looking through the inherited methods once more I came across `createContainer(...)` which I used as `createContainer("/mytheme.res", "LoginDialog");`

This is a working solution that I could find at this time, but I'm still open for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to create a new instace of a `Component`. The method findSomething is used for the `Components` which you have created in the Resource Editor. If you want to create a new Object which is not in the Resource Editor´s interfaces, you must use the

```
createContainer(Resources res, "Name in the Resource editor of this Component")
```